# ImageButton crashes app

Tags: android, image

Whenever I hit one of my two image buttons (EditButton, SaveButton), my app crashes.

The error's the same everytime:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method
>   onSaveClicked(view) in the activity class
>   com.example.groceryrunner.MainActivity for onClick handler on view
>   class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'SaveButton'

The thing is I don't even have an onSaveClicked(view) method in any event in my xml. I've tried all sorts of combinations with the actual method that the button is supposed to go to when clicked (onCreateLGClick), but it doesn't affect anything since my app never gets there. Also, the only button that does work isn't consistent, many times nothing happens or takes 10 clicks to make its event go off, even though it's worked before(CreateLG button).

createlgmenu (xml):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Create_List"
        android:title="@string/Create_List"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Create_Food_Group"
        android:title="@string/Create_Food_Group"/>
   </menu>
```

menu (xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

activity main (xml):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/GetStarted"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:text="Select or Create a list to get started!"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/EditButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SaveButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListName"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/edit_button"
    android:onClick="onCreateLGClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/CreateLG"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ListName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListsButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:onClick="onCreateLGClick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ListName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Grocery Runner"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:onClick="onCreateLGClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ListsButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/GetStarted"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="≡"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/SaveButton"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/GetStarted"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditButton"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="onCreateLGClick"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/save_disk" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.groceryrunner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Button Save = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onCreateLGClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    /*switch (id) {
    case R.id.CreateLG:
        findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        createLGMenu(v);
        break;
    case R.id.ListsButton:
        findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        createLGMenu(v);
        break;
    }*/
}


public void createLGMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu LGMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    LGMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.createlgmenu, LGMenu.getMenu());
    LGMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            String choice = new String((String) item.getTitle());
            if (choice == "Create_List") {
                createListDialog();
            }
            else if (choice == "Create_Group") {
                createListDialog();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    LGMenu.show();
}

public AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
private void createListDialog() {
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    EditText textInput = new EditText(this);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Create list");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Name your list: ");
    dialogBuilder.setView(textInput);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Create", new   DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            findViewById(R.id.ListName).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(), "List has been created.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            // add list to ListsButton
            //findViewById(R.id.ListName). -> Change ListName text to created list
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(), "List has been created.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    });
    // Output
    AlertDialog dialogue = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialogue.show();

  }

}
```

Comment: Post your createLGMenu.xml, also post the menu xml called main.xml

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: Trying that now, just trying to figure out why my MaiActivity.java file no longer recognizes my xml files.

Comment: What do you mean it does not recognise them, what does the error say? This could be the root problem

Comment: @user2100364 Please post your full logcat error. I have tried your code and it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @user2100364 Check out and try with answer posted by me. Its working fine on  my side.

Comment: I mean that it's not detecting the files. I'm now getting an error saying that bin\resources.ap_ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found my fix! First, since I was encountering other errors, I just saved my code and deleted Eclipse and reinstalled/extracted from Android's site again. The button is no longer crashing my app.

Furthermore, the xml files that weren't being recognized were another big hindrance that I fixed with the help from AdamM:

1) I deleted the R import

2) Commented out the lines that were giving me errors in recognizing my xml files

3) Restarted Eclipse & Built All

Answer (score 1):

In your

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

You have inflated the `main.xml` menu. Are you sure its not the `createlgmenu.xml`  that you need to inflate?

Answer (score 0):

Try out below its working fine on my side. Hope will work for you also.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Button Save = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onCreateLGClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.CreateLG:
            findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            createLGMenu(v);
            break;
        case R.id.ListsButton:
            findViewById(R.id.GetStarted).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            createLGMenu(v);
            break;
        }

    }

    public void createLGMenu(View v) {
        PopupMenu LGMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        LGMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.createmenu, LGMenu.getMenu());
        LGMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.Create_List:
                    createListDialog();
                    break;
                case R.id.Create_Food_Group:
                    createListDialog();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                /*
                 * String choice = new String((String) item.getTitle()); if
                 * (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Create_List")){ createListDialog();
                 * } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Create_Group")) {
                 * createListDialog(); }
                 */
                return true;
            }
        });
        LGMenu.show();
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;

    private void createListDialog() {
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        EditText textInput = new EditText(this);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Create list");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("Name your list: ");
        dialogBuilder.setView(textInput);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Create",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        findViewById(R.id.ListName).setVisibility(
                                View.INVISIBLE);
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(),
                        // "List has been created.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        // add list to ListsButton
                        // findViewById(R.id.ListName). -> Change ListName text
                        // to created list
                    }
                });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContent(),
                        // "List has been created.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                });
        // Output
        AlertDialog dialogue = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialogue.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: I will try this once I can, unfortunately eclipse won't let me try anything since bin/resource.ap_ "doesn't exist". I'm trying all sorts of solutions but haven't fixed it yet. I'd reinstall Eclipse, but it's my folder that's missing the file that's the problem.